# Merge 2 sql queries

Tags: sql, expressionengine

I have 2 sql queries running separately, what I would like to do is merge the two so I can extract both sets of data within one query.

The queries are using the ExpressionEngine query module and are below, I would like to extract total and total_2 in one query:

Query 1:

```
 SELECT COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total
 FROM exp_channel_data 
 JOIN exp_channel_titles 
     ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id
 WHERE field_id_207 != '' 
     AND status = 'open'
     AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18'
     AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

Query 2:

```
 SELECT COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total_2
 FROM exp_channel_data
 JOIN exp_channel_titles
    ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id 
  WHERE status = 'open' 
    AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18'
    AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it. Both Querys look the same to me except one has a WHERE in it. Doesn't Query #2 has what Query #1 have inside of it?

Comment: Hi Nick, they are very similar the only difference is query 1 is pulling results for all entries which field_id_207 is not empty. Field_id_207 is a field relating to other entires, so I'm pulling the total entries (query 2) and the number of entires with related entries (query 1). Thanks :)

Comment: I still don't get it, Your query #2 includes Query #1 in it, there's no way you can join them because then you would obtain duplicate rows. Which is why you're getting errors when trying any of the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN field_id_207 != '' then 1 else 0 end) as total_1,
    COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total_2 
FROM exp_channel_data 
JOIN exp_channel_titles 
ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id 
AND status = 'open' 
AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' 
AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the response. I'm getting a Error 500 (Internal Server Error) with this query, same with the ones below. I'm currently running on a MAMP local setup.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two queries with `union`

```
SELECT COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total  FROM exp_channel_data JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id WHERE field_id_207 != '' AND status = 'open' AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"

union

SELECT COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total_2 FROM exp_channel_data JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id AND status = 'open' AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

you may need to add another field to distinguish which query you are looking at

```
SELECT 'q1' source, COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total  FROM exp_channel_data JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id WHERE field_id_207 != '' AND status = 'open' AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"

union

SELECT 'q2' source, COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total_2 FROM exp_channel_data JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id AND status = 'open' AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query like this. Given that you haven't said which SQL dialect you're using, your mileage may vary.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN field_id_207 != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total, COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total_2
FROM exp_channel_data 
JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id 
WHERE status = 'open' 
AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18'" 
AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```

The benefit of doing this over doing a union is that a union-based approach may require twice the effort on the part of the server - depending on the engine and it's optimisation approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two queries with `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, the first removes duplicates while the second doesn't (therefore the second is often faster). But it is often better (and faster) to adjust your query to select the two results at the same time.

In this case:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS count_total_entryid, 
    SUM(IF(field_id_207!='';1;0)) AS count_nonempty_entryid 
FROM exp_channel_data 
JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id 
WHERE status = 'open'
    AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '18' 
     AND author_id = "CURRENT_USER"
```